# Where head of this Link list points after recursive statement

Tags: c, recursion, reverse, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have simple link list program, that would create/print it, and later on print the last 2 number from it (in reverse order)

```
cat link_list.c 
/**
 * C program to create and traverse a Linked List
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Structure of a node */
struct node {
    int data;          // Data 
    struct node *next; // Address 
}*head;


/* 
 * Functions to create and display list
 */
void createList(int n);
void traverseList();
void ReverseList(struct node *);


int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter the total number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    createList(n);

    printf("\nData in the list \n");
    traverseList();

    ReverseList(head);

    return 0;
}

/*
 * Create a list of n nodes
 */
void createList(int n)
{
    struct node *newNode, *temp;
    int data, i;

    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // Terminate if memory not allocated
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
        exit(0);
    }


    // Input data of node from the user
    printf("Enter the data of node 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);

    head->data = data; // Link data field with data
    head->next = NULL; // Link address field to NULL


    // Create n - 1 nodes and add to list
    temp = head;
    for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        /* If memory is not allocated for newNode */
        if(newNode == NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
            break;
        }

        printf("Enter the data of node %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &data);

        newNode->data = data; // Link data field of newNode
        newNode->next = NULL; // Make sure new node points to NULL 

        temp->next = newNode; // Link previous node with newNode
        temp = temp->next;    // Make current node as previous node
    }
}


/*
 * Display entire list
 */
void traverseList()
{
    struct node *temp;

    // Return if list is empty 
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty.");
        return;
    }
    
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("Data = %d\n", temp->data); // Print data of current node
        temp = temp->next;                 // Move to next node
    }
}

static count=0, k=2;

ReverseList(struct node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;
    else {
        ReverseList(head->next);
        count++;
        if (count <= k)
            printf("Data = %d\n", head->data);
    }
}
```

For an input 1 2 3 , it would first print 3 2 1 and then 3 2 correctly but I have confusion about the :

```
    if (head == NULL)
        return;
```

what exactly it returns with return;, and where head is pointing after the
ReverseList(head->next); statement ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Before making any code involving lists or trees or similar linked structures, I recommend you use pencil and paper to draw all operations. Draw boxes for the nodes and arrows for all pointers. Erase and redraw the arrows as you perform the operations. While doing this write down a numbered list of the operations you perform. Do all this until you got something that seems to work, and then turn the numbered list into code to perform the operations one by one.

Comment: When you get to implementing the algorithms, do it bit by bit. Divide all the points from the previous step (the drawing and making a list of operations) into smaller and simpler steps, and continue to sub-divide the steps until it's not possible to divide them further. Then implement each small sub-step one by one, building with extra warning enabled (that you treat as errors that must be fixed), and test. Only when it builds cleanly *and* works, you continue to the next small step.

Comment: Then when you have a problem with one of your small pieces, you use a debugger to step through the relevant code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. And again use pencil and paper to draw up the operations you perform, and compare them to the original drawing and itemized (and sub-divided) list you have. If there's any deviation from what you have on paper then that's probably the problem.

Comment: @AlexF, But head is null after  ReverseList(head->next); , how could it print head->data successfully, that is the main doubt I have ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Yeah divided the list to just 3 numbers to understand it better, and then on paper wrote down what is being pushed on to the stack first, for instance , first it would push return address and then address of head node, and then next return address and address of next node from head. but once base condition is reached, I have doubts understanding the unwind path. WIsh you just see where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you forgot to specify the return type of the function in the function definition:

```
ReverseList(struct node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;
    else {
        ReverseList(head->next);
        count++;
        if (count <= k)
            printf("Data = %d\n", head->data);
    }
}
```

You have to write:

```
void ReverseList(struct node *head)
```

As for your question:

> I have confusion about the :
>
> ```
> if (head == NULL)
>     return;
> ```
>
> what exactly it returns with return;, and where head is pointing after the ReverseList(head->next); statement ?

Then as the function has the return type `void` and the return statement does not include an expression then the return statement returns nothing.

The function parameter `head` is a local variable of the function. The function does not change the pointer head declared in the file scope

```
struct node {
    int data;          // Data 
    struct node *next; // Address 
}*head;
```

In the first call of the function the parameter head has the value of the global variable head due to this statement:

```
 ReverseList(head);
```

If the value is not equal to NULL then the function recursively calls itself passing the value of the  pointer `head->next`:

```
ReverseList(head->next);
```

So in the second recursive call of the function itself the value of its parameter `head` is equal to the value of `head->next` where in this expression `head` is the function parameter of the previous call of the function.

That is the parameter head at first gets the value of the global variable `head` and then the parameter is initialized sequentially by values of the data member `next` of the next node in the sequence.

So for the list that contains nodes with values 1, 2, 3 you have

1-st call
parameter head is equal to the global variable head

2-nd call
parameter head is equal to head->next that points to the node with the value 1

3-rd call
parameter head is equal to head->next->next that points to the node with the value 2

4-th call
parameter head is equal to head->next->next->next that points to the node with the value 3

5-th call
parameter head is equal to head->next->next->next->next and equal to NULL

Pay attention to that it is not a good idea to use static global variables within the function

```
static count=0, k=2;
```

You need to remember reinitialize them if you want to call the function one more time. It is better to make the variable `k` a function parameter.

The function could be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int push( struct node **head, int data )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( *new_node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }
    
    return success;
}

void display( const struct node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

size_t display_last_n( const struct node *head, size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        i = display_last_n( head->next, n ) + 1;
        
        if ( !( n < i ) )
        {
            if ( i != 1 ) printf( ", " );
            printf( "%d", head->data );
        }
    }
    
    return i;
}

void clear( struct node **head )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        struct node *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int n = N; n--; )
    {
        push( &head, n );
    }
    
    display( head );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        display_last_n( head, i + 1 );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    clear( &head );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is:

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
9
9, 8
9, 8, 7
9, 8, 7, 6
9, 8, 7, 6, 5
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have a simple three-node list like this:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
```

When we initially call `ReverseList` we pass the `1` node as the `head` and we have this call-chain:

```
ReverseList(1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL)
  ReverseList(2 -> 3 -> NULL)
    ReverseList(3 -> NULL)
      ReverseList(NULL)
    printf(3)
  printf(2)
printf(1)
```

Comment: Actually, @Alex F has pointed out that head is NULL after  ReverseList(head->next);
on the return path but then head->data inside printf statement should cause some issues instead its printing out the values in reverse order, how ?

Comment: @Milan When `head == NULL` the function returns and doesn't dereference `head`. In the previous call the local variable `head` isn't `NULL`, it's still points to the `3` node. You have to remember that `head` is a local variable in each call, its value will be the one used in the call `ReverseList(head->next)`, but that doesn't modify the value of `head` in the function doing that call.